# google script openById : You do not have permission to perform that action

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, triggers

An event driven script in a spreadsheet opens another spreadsheet

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(otherSpreadsheetId);
```

Looking at the execution transcript, I get the following error

> SpreadsheetApp.openById([0AjqSnE_p3nFqdDN0LWpFbjFqVDRwNmFGOV91QzZrZc])
>   [0 seconds] Execution failed: You do not have permission to perform
>   that action.

When I run the function directly in the debugger, I successfully open the other spreadsheet. When the function is run by an "onEdit" event, then I get the error.

Do I need to enable a particular API?

Comment: Read about "onEdit" triggers and AuthMode: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events Have a look at installable triggers. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable Sorry, it is a lot of reading, it is complex.

Comment: Indeed, a simple trigger (which I used so far) cannot alter another file, according to the docs. I've setup an installable trigger which successfully opens the other spreadsheet. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Installable Triggers

There are two types of OnEdit trigger. Installable triggers are able to 'alter another file', see: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

[@kusi supplied the answer as a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27744929/google-script-openbyid-you-do-not-have-permission-to-perform-that-action#comment43923501_27744929), just adding it here.

Comment: Links and all, sorry, but I really don't find this useful at all. This one should be the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49063346/5871613

Answer (score 3):

You can set up an installable trigger programmatically in the current sheet and this way the `openById` can be called.

```
function onOpen() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myOnEdit')
   .onEdit()
   .create();
}

function myOnEdit(e){
   SpreadsheetApp.openById('id_of_other_sheet');
}
```

Comment: This is the direct answer (manual trigger version). It's much easier to understand the document now. Lol.