# Google script (copy row to other sheet onEdit)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have this code in google sheets:

```
function copy(row) {
  var value = sheet.getRange(row, 1).getValue();
  sheet.getRange(row, 3).setValue(value);
}
```

Then i change function onEdit

```
function onEdit(e){
  var range = e.range;
  copy(range.getRow());
}
```

Now this script copy some row, who we edit.

But i needed copy this row to other sheet. And if i make like this:

```
function copy(row) {
  var value = sheet.getRange(row, 1).getValue();
  var sheetTo = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID).getSheetByName(NAME);
  sheetTo.getRange(row, 3).setValue(value);
}
```

It is not working. (If call function from editor it working well)

Please, help

Comment: Anastasia, welcome to SO! Could you please inform us what error (if any) you've received?

Comment: i dont know where i can see errors. always it show me like popup in editor, but now i have not any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to use `sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange);`instead `setValue`

Comment: it used only in the same board

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot refer to an external sheet for the onEdit trigger.
See here: [google script openById : You do not have permission to perform that action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27744929/google-script-openbyid-you-do-not-have-permission-to-perform-that-action)