# Google Sheets Arrayformula to only update new rows not existing rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, xlookup

I have used the following formula which updates values from another sheet and returns the last value from the Xloopup.

=(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B<>"",XLOOKUP(B2:B,Estimation!B2:B,Estimation!Y2:Y,"",0,-1),"")))

I want the new rows to be affected not the ones on which the formula has already been applied previously. Any means i can do this.

Thanks

The sheet before the last row as shown below is entered had a different value and once the last row is entered the entire document is getting updated since the lookup value is the same.

UHID (Column being referred)
IRK000001
IRK000002
IRK000001

Treatment ID (to be updated)
TRE0000003 - This was originally TRE000001 but based on above data since both the referring values matched the data has been updated to a new number)
TRE0000002
TRE0000003

Comment: Please share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The use case that you are trying to achieve is not doable with [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) because it's default behavior is to continuously validate the condition you have enclosed within it and returns the whole resulting dataset.

Employing an [App Script OnEdit() trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) is a more sure way to accomplish this requirement, you can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38695652/google-script-copy-row-to-other-sheet-onedit) for reference.