# How to allow onEdit() to access Google Drive files and folders

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a Google Apps Script function, `push_permissions()`, that reads permissions from a Spreadsheet and applies them to Google Drive files and folders. The function works as expected when manually run, but I wanted to automatically trigger this function every time edits are made on a certain range. So I made this `onEdit()` function:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart == 10 && e.range.rowStart > 2 && e.value.includes('@gmail.com')) push_permissions();
};
```

Whenever `onEdit()` is triggered, it throws this error:

```
Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
at onEdit(Permissions:2:27)
```

Any way to make this work?

Comment: Yes the scope was added since the function works on its own. push_permissions starts with this: `let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxx-ID-xxxx/');` And yes, V8 enabled.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new in GAS. Can you please point me out on how I would do that? Thank you!

Comment: Do what? "Try putting that scope in your manifest file." Thanks. I tried the installable trigger but it threw the same error. I followed this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49063346/2756066

Comment: Take a look  at this:https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208611/discussion-between-cooper-and-majal).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onEdit` has the simple type of Google Apps Script Triggers.

For getting full access of scopes you have to install the trigger for EDIT event.

Please check [Managing triggers manually](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) for that.