# SpreadsheetApp.openById displays error when run via the onOpen command

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-sheets-custom-function

I suspect this is a simple fix but I'm having problems in my Google App Script, I have read a number of posts that indicate these functions are deprecated in custom functions but I'm lost how to fix.

I have a script that is run automatically when the Google Sheet is opened using the onOpen() function. I tried to move the OpenByID() method inside this function but get the same error. Can someone tell me how to fix this specifically please.

```
function onOpen(e) {
//function test(e) {
  // Add a custom menu to the spreadsheet.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var masterSheet=ss.getSheetByName(masterTab);

  for(var xLOSName = 3; xLOSName <= 4; xLOSName++) 
  {
    Logger.log('Attempting to open file');
    var fileId = masterSheet.getRange(xLOSName,2).getValue();
    Logger.log('Opening File ID: ' + fileId);
    var xLOSSpreadsheet  = SpreadsheetApp.openById(masterSheet.getRange(xLOSName,2).getValue());

    //var xLOSSpreadsheet  = SpreadsheetApp.openById(masterSheet.getRange(xLOSName,2).getValue()).getSheets()[0];
    Logger.log(xLOSSpreadsheet.getName());
  }
```

NOTE: It never get to the point of logging the name of the file. Stupidly, this works when running from the debugger.
Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [google script openById : You do not have permission to perform that action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27744929/google-script-openbyid-you-do-not-have-permission-to-perform-that-action)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use SpreadsheetApp.openById() in custom functions. It's not just deprecated it's not allowed.

[Restrictions on Custom Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services)

Also simple triggers like onOpen() cannot perform operations that require permission.

[Simple Triggers Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)

If you require operations that require permission you must use installable triggers.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried running that same code but from a custom function different from onOpen()?
I have had similar problems that were in the end limitations on the onOpen() and onEdit() functions, and I was also looking for sintax errors and such...